# Did Melisandre use Wildfire (ADWD)?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

**WARNING:** *A Dance With Dragons* spoilers ahead!

In one of Jon's POV chapters we see

> Mance get burned (almost) alive. But before that Melisandre sets fire to [The Horn of Joramun](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Horn_of_Winter).

What I find interesting is that it seems as though she uses [Wildfire](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Wildfire) to achieve the burn, but it is nowhere stated explicitly whether this is true or not.

Here is the relevant text (I have highlighted the important parts):

> FREE FOLK!” cried Melisandre. “Behold the fate of those who choose the darkness!”
> The Horn of Joramun burst into flame.
> It went up with a whoosh as swirling tongues of **green and yellow fire** leapt up crackling all along its length.
> *-A Song of Ice and Fire: A Dance With Dragons - Part One (Dreams and Dust), Jon.*

Reasons why I think it's Wildfire:

- "Green and yellow" seem to me a characteristic of Wildfire
- When I think about it you probably *would* need Wildfire to burn a horn that big
- Melisandre and the Red Priest are quite similar and Thoros uses wildfire to light his sword<sup>[1](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Wildfire)</sup>

Comment: It's more likely the horn is somehow magical itself.

Comment: But Mance stated that they never found the real horn, they just took the biggest one they had ever seen from a giant's grave...

Comment: Judging by the precautions the alchemists took with wildfire, storing it in cool cellars and under water, with sand traps to quench any fire, it feels unlikely that Melisandre is carrying wildfire around with her. In her POV however, we saw that she carried around lots of powders to create various fire and smoke effects, so if I had to guess, I would say it was a powder. Fireworks.

Comment: @TLP Fireworks **does** seem very plausible, especially with the "crackling all up its length" part of the quote.

Answer (score 5):

### It's a distinct possibility

**TV Spoilers:**

> In the seventh episode of season 4 "Mockingbird", Melisandre reveals to Queen Selyse that she employs various chemicals to create the pyrotechnics she uses in her sermons and devotions. Someone as knowledgeable about fire as Melisandre would definitely know about Wildfire. So it's a real possibility that she did use it to burn the Horn of Joramun in that dramatic manner.

Comment: One can only wonder how much she is lying about seeing things in the flames.